# Maven copy/paste (BIRT) resources at design time

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, birt

I have several projects which include BIRT reports. All these projects are Maven projects. Obviously, in order to try to reuse some of my BIRT components, I'm using BIRT libraries (.rptlibrary files).

For couple of these BIRT librairies, I would like to include them as a Maven dependency from an external common project. The problem is that BIRT needs these rptlibrary physically at design time, and not only at build/run time.

With Maven, is it possible to physically copy some dependency file at design time instead of build time ?

In other word, is it possible for Maven to copy/paste the content of a src/main/resource folder from a source project to a target project at design time ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is "design time"? Maven is not something that know "time" - it has "phases", "life-cycles" and "goals". Compile, install, validate… but you have to run it, there is no other way. You can create a custom goal and call it whatever you like, make it copy whatever file you need. Still, you will have to use `mvn something:something`

Comment: By "design time" I meant a phase before the compilation, but I phase that you shouldn't execute. I could do what I wanted by using "dependency:unpack".